# Pivot wider with duplicate information

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataset that describes the physical condition of buildings, identified in the dummy data by "ID". The conditions that it covers includes describing the foundation, the condition, and the exterior of the buildings. The problem is, some buildings have, for example, more than one exterior finish, and it has two entries for exterior. I want to pivot the dataframe from long to wide, but these duplicates are tripping me up.

Is there a way to take the dummy data below, and just include both values from the DESCR column in the names_from TYPE column? Like, for structure 3 it would be aluminum & stucco?

Dummy data below:

```
struct_data <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4),
                             TYPE = c("Foundation", "Condition", "Exterior", "Foundation", 
                                      "Foundation", "Condition", "Exerior",
                                      "Foundation", "Condition", "Exterior", "Exterior",
                                      "Foundation", "Condition", "Exterior"),
                             DESCR = c("Slab", "Fair", "Brick", "Crawl Space",
                                       "Crawl Space", "Good", "Stucco",
                                       "Crawl Space", "Bad", "Aluminum", "Stucco",
                                       "Slab", "Fair", "Brick")
)


library(tidyverse)

wide_struct_data <- struct_data %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = TYPE,
    values_from = DESCR
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
struct_data |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = TYPE, values_from = DESCR, values_fn = ~ paste(c(.x), collapse = " & "))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 5
     ID Foundation         Condition Exterior          Exerior
  <dbl> <chr>              <chr>     <chr>             <chr>  
1     1 Slab & Crawl Space Fair      Brick             NA     
2     2 Crawl Space        Good      NA                Stucco 
3     3 Crawl Space        Bad       Aluminum & Stucco NA     
4     4 Slab               Fair      Brick             NA
```

Comment: I took what you said literally. If you want them to be in a list, you can make it be `values_fn = list`)